# Android - Void methods cannot return a value

Tags: android, methods, tablelayout, void

I have an activity with a tablelayout. I put text into the layout from string arrays. But now I get the error: "Void methods cannot return a value"

```
public class stop10 extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

String[] column1;
String[] column2;
View view;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stop10);

    TableLayout prices = (TableLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.table);
    String[] column1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.column1);
    String[] column2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.column2);
    prices.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    prices.bringToFront();
    for(int i = 0; i < column1.length; i++){
        TableRow tr =  new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        TextView c1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        c1.setText(column1[i]);
        TextView c2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        c2.setText(column2[i]);
        tr.addView(c1);
        tr.addView(c2);
        prices.addView(tr);

    }
    return view;

}
```

I understand that the void method cannot return value, but what else should I use now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it says `Void methods cannot return a value` then you should remove `return view;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize table layout in this manner

```
TableLayout prices = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
```

Also remove

```
return view;
```

You do not have to return view in oncreate method.

```
setContentView(R.layout.stop10);
```

handles the view.